# Conversion from Linq to String

Tags: string, linq

Am newbie here and tried the search, but not quite understood it, so I am thinking to ask to the forum for help.

I want to get the result into the text box from the following code but got an error.
Confused on how to overcome it, appreciate for any help.  I believe it was an error on the conversion from linqIgroup to string to be put in textboxt.Text

It's about to display the most word(s) that has been occurred in a text file.

```
string sentence;
        string[] result = {""};
        sentence = txtParagraph.Text;
        char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', '.', '?', '!' };

        string[] splitStr = sentence.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var dic = splitStr.ToLookup(w => w.ToLowerInvariant());
        var orderedDic = dic.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count(m=>m.First()).ToString()));

        txtFreqWord.Text = orderedDic.ToString();
```

Comment: "but got an error" --- is it a secret error?

Comment: You can use `String.Join` on the dictionary's `Values` property, if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to do what you are after. I am using regular expressions aswell.

```
            var resultsList = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("normal text here normal normal".ToLower(), @"\W+") 
        .Where(s => s.Length > 3)
        .GroupBy(s => s)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());

        string mostFrequent = resultsList.FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

To get all of them with their count, do the following :

```
            foreach (var x in resultsList) {
                 txtFreqWord.Text = txtFreqWord.Text + x.Key + " " + x.Count() +", ";
            }
```

Comment: Stephen, you nail it, but it takes me to understand the logic behind it, sorry haven't got any reputation to vote up.  Thanks a lot.  The key is on: string mostFrequent = resultsList.FirstOrDefault().Key;

Comment: Will do John, one more question if you don't mind, how about if I wanna show the whole keys(Words) which has occurred most, example: John(occured 3x), David(occured 3x) instead only John, should I pass it into string array?

Comment: Thank you fr your answer, it's helpful, but maybe it was my wrong on my comment, what I meant was that I need to show on my Textbox both name: John, David; while on the first answer would only come up with one name.  And for the updated answer, I am a bit confused on how to put it into a Textbox, will it show ex: John, David.  I tried to do it but it seems it didn't update the answer on the Textbox.

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how to add text to the textbox.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, try to fiddle diddle with it to get only display the most Word(s) that occurred.  Tried this: txtFreqWord.Text = txtFreqWord.Text + x.Key + ", "; but it will display the whole words in descending order of occurrances, I guess I have to put something afer x.Key so I had tried Max(), IndexOf, but they gave me only first element of the word (char) and error instead only the top occurrence Word(s), any final tip?, >.<

Comment: Tried this, but gave me error:   foreach (var x in orderedDic.FirstOrDefault())
            {
                txtFreqWord.Text = txtFreqWord.Text + x.Key + ", ";
            }

Comment: Just Looking how to print the most occurrences word(s), so if there are 3 words with the same occurrences, it will only print those 3 words. i.e: Jack, Daniel, Petra.  While others with less occurrences will not be printed.  Still not succeed so far....

Comment: You can the group by part to this : .GroupBy(s => s).Where(x=>x.Count() > 1)... That way you are getting words which have more then 1 occurrence.